# How to downgrade PHP from 5.5.9 to 5.4 in Ubuntu 14.04 (Installed with LAMP)

Tags: 14.04, php, mysql, lamp, downgrade

I need to downgrade my PHP version from 5.5.9 to 5.4 (using Ubuntu 14.04), because I have a code that's using mySQL (which is deprecated in 5.5.9), and I cannot change that code. Is there a way to do it?

*I tried the other threads that I saw about that issue in the site, but I couldn't find anything that helped me.

Comment: How can I roll back after this command. I can't install phpmyadmin now

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First you need to remove all php5 files :

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge `dpkg -l | grep php | grep -w 5.5 | awk '{print $2}' | xargs`
```

After that try to search for php 5.4. available resources :

```
apt-cache policy php5
```

My result :

```
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

If there is no resources available than we need to add some by following command :

```
echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

and

```
apt-get update
```

If there is a problem with signatures like following :

```
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://php53.dotdeb.org stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY xxxxxCODExxxx
```

we need to sign our Deb repository by commands :

```
gpg --keyserver keys.gnupg.net --recv-key xxxxxCODExxxx
gpg -a --export xxxxxCODExxxx | sudo apt-key add - apt-get update
```

After that execute :

```
sudo apt-get update
apt-cache policy php5
```

you should see last result :

```
php5:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4
  Version table:
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4.4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.9+dfsg-1ubuntu4 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
     5.4.33-1~dotdeb.1 0
        500 http://php53.dotdeb.org/ stable/all amd64 Packages
```

and finally install your version by hitting :

```
apt-get install php5=5.4.33-1~dotdeb.1
```

Enjoy ;)

Comment: select it as ur answer

Comment: I don't have enough reputation :(

Comment: It didn't work...

Comment: please note the EXACT version of php 5.4 available. the final step didn't work for me until I changed to 5.4.34 which is what is currently available. 5.4.33 is not there anymore

Comment: I followed these instructions and there were no errors, the output of the final command `apt-get install php5=5.4.35-1~dotdeb.1` indicated that it was installing the correct version, but `php --version` still show `PHP 5.5.9-1ubuntu4.5`

Comment: @RTF I have exactly the same issue - did you resolve it?

Comment: @benedict_w I didn't unfortunately, i just removed my legacy php dependency, which was the ultimate but most painful solution. If u can't get it working, you might have to build php from source

Comment: Instructions for building from source on 14.04: https://stavrovski.net/blog/build-and-install-php-5329-from-source-on-an-ubuntu-1404-lts-server

Comment: Thanks. I am using Laravel 3 and it looks like an easy fix (https://github.com/laravel/laravel/commit/3298407238fd3e212cdf8d829adc6f519b941052) so I will just try and get it working on PHP 5.5 for now

Comment: I got `W: Failed to fetch copy:/var/lib/apt/lists/partial/php53.dotdeb.org_dists_stable_all_binary-amd64_Packages  Invalid file format` after adding http://php53.dotdeb.org to sources.list

Comment: @aniruddha.sarkar I got error like kiradotee says.

Comment: Same error, still showing 5.5.9 with php -v. The weird thing is that with apt-cache policy php shows 5.4 installed.

Answer (score 3):

add dotdeb repo by following command :

```
echo "deb http://php53.dotdeb.org stable all" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Fetch and install the GnuPG key

```
wget http://www.dotdeb.org/dotdeb.gpg
sudo apt-key add dotdeb.gpg
```

Then

```
sudo apt-get update
```

The easy way to install the specific version is via synaptic

[image]

all done

[image]

also you should downgrade the apache to install right "**libapache2-mod-php5**"

add precise repo by the following command

```
echo "deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu precise-security main" | sudo tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list && sudo apt-get update
```

then

```
sudo aptitude install apache2=2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7
```

make sure you accept the following

The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

> Install the following packages:
>   1) apache2-mpm-prefork [2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 (precise-security)]
>   2) apache2.2-bin [2.2.22-1ubuntu1.7 (precise-security)]

then

```
sudo aptitude install libapache2-mod-php5=5.4.36-1~dotdeb.1
```

don't forget to set specific version when try to install an php package

```
sudo aptitude install php5-mysql=5.4.36-1~dotdeb.1
```

Comment: @fareednamrouti glad it will help you

Comment: No gui for the wicked :( Running Ubuntu server.